# Is there a difference in performance between Ubuntu-only computer and Ubuntu installed on a Windows machine?

Tags: system-installation, windows, performance

I mostly work with Ubuntu, but most computers available in my workplace come with Windows 7 or 8 or 10 already installed. I can either install Ubuntu in addition to Windows, or install Ubuntu after removing Windows. Besides the disk-space, is there any difference in performance between these options?

E.g, when I boot into Ubuntu, is it possible that the installed Windows will waste some system resources?

Comment: The only problem I know of between the 2 is the "time". Windows stores it in BIOS as local time and Linux uses UTC. There is NO interaction between the 2 OS's in a dual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, you should not experience a decrease in performance

The only thing that is negatively-impacted by running a dual-boot is your drive space. While this may have other side effects that may cause a decrease in performance, it is not necessarily caused by a dual-boot specific performance decrease.

Disregarding drive space, you will not be experiencing any performance losses because only 1 operating system is going to be running at a time, therefore the other operating system cannot be making any calls and taking away CPU time or RAM.

Answer (score 1):

As long as Ubuntu is running on dual-boot, as opposed to in a virtual machine, the only system resource Windows will take up when you're in Ubuntu is hard disk space.  As long as you have enough space available for the Ubuntu OS (20 GB is adequate, 30 GB is better), swap (2x RAM) and /home (as big as you'll need for your storage and tarball installs), it should run as well as it would on a dedicated computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only boot one operating system at a time! If you boot only one operating system all the time, it will remain preloaded in RAM memory, thus booting faster. When you switch from one OS to the other, the RAM memory is erased and the other OS is loaded into RAM, thus longer boot time might occur (like in a first time boot, a.k.a. cold boot).

The specific performance of each OS is independent from other OSes, it only depends on the way it functions internally. Typically, Windows performance decreases with time, Ubuntu performance increases with time (because Ubuntu preloads in RAM the most used programs and files).